# Lebesgue's criterion for Riemann integrability of bounded real valued functions defined on compact metric spaces

Tags: analysis, integration, metric-spaces, compactness

Let $(X, d)$ be a compact metric space, and let $S$ be the algebra of sets generated by the open and closed balls of $X$. Suppose we have a pre-measure defined on $S$ such that the measure of each open ball is equal to the measure of its corresponding closed ball. Then a bounded real valued function defined on $X$ is Riemann integrable iff it is discontinuous on a set of measure zero.

This is the topic of a paper I found:
http://emis.matem.unam.mx/journals/HOA/IJMMS/Volume1_1/74.pdf

I don't quite understand the significance of requiring that the measure of each open ball be equal to the measure of its corresponding closed ball. The author provides an example in which the statement does not hold due to the condition on the balls being omitted, but I am still at a loss. If anyone could shed more light on this situation, I'd be very grateful.

EDIT:

Could we say that for $f \colon X \to \mathbb R$ and $E \subset X$ that $f$ is discontinuous at $x \in E$ iff $f \cdot \chi_{E}$ is discontinuous at $x \in E$? Then $f \cdot \chi_{E}$ is discontinuous at all points in $E$ where $f$ is discontinuous and at all points that are in the boundary of $E$. Therefore, we want the boundary of $E$ to be small enough so that it doesn't contribute too many discontinuities?

Is this reasoning correct or at least on the right track? I really appreciate any input that you guys have.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The author is just requiring that because he wants the measure of the boundary of a ball to be 0. If this were not the case then, as the author showed, we can easily find examples of functions that are Riemann integrable by the given definition but the boundary does not have measure 0. This happens because the author used step functions to define integrability. So step functions are trivially integrable. This is a definition independent of the measure so it doesn't depend on whether the boundary has measure 0 or not.

Comment: I can see from the example provided that if we do not have that the boundary of each ball has measure zero, then we can find a function that is Riemann integrable but is discontinuous on a set with measure greater than zero. I am looking for a good explanation as to why that is, though.

Comment: It is because we defined integrability in terms of approximations by step functions. Step functions are trivially approximated by step functions and hence integrable. This definition of integrability had no mention of measure of the boundary so to ensure that no counterexamples can be produced we must at least require that the boundary of balls have measure 0 since step functions are built on top of them and are always integrable by the definition of integrability. It turns out that this requirement on the trivial elements of integration is sufficient. Hope that helped.

Comment: It did. Thank you for your help.